# Angular CLI refuses to pass in ng command

Tags: angular, cmd, terminal, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I have been trying since last week to install the Angular CLI correctly in my Mac. I have concluded that it might be Apple's new operating system (Mac OS Catalina) that isn't letting me advance in any way.

I have tried uninstalling node.js and installing it back, uninstalling the Angular CLI, restarting terminal, and restarting my mac. Nothing seems to work. I have already tried

```
 npm install -g @angular-cli
```

And

```
npm link @angular/cli
```

Keep in mind I have Mac OS Catalina installed as well as Z shell instead of bash since it asked me much earlier to upload it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved it! It took some experimenting and deep search about the topic to solve it.

The main thing happening was that the ng command didn't exist. I knew this but I had no idea how to solve it. Eventually, I figured out there's a directory called node_modules in the `cd ~/` of the terminal. In the end, I traveled down to the alias @angular/cli/bin/ng within the `cd ~/node-modules` (@angular was the only one there) Furthermore, I made the ng alias myself...

```
alias ng="~/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

Thant's all it took! Does anyone know why the ng command wasn't there already?

Comment: Maybe it's an npm issue for Mac OS Catalina? You should post this issue on the Angular CLI Github